# PHP - Key of associative array can't be assigned

Tags: php

I have a homework about associative array. But, the key of the array can't be assigned.

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   // $code and $name are from database 
   $array += array("$code" => "$name");
}
print_r($array);
```

Instead of showing

```
Array (
    [123] => dave 
    [234] => linda 
)
```

it shows

```
Array ( 
    [0] => dave 
    [1] => linda 
)
```

What happen?

Comment: Where would you expect to get 123 and 234 from? What are `$code` and `$name`? Show that part of the code too.

Comment: Your `$code` value appears to be coming back as something you're not expecting. We'll need to see where it's coming from in order to figure out what's actually occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do array assignment like below:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $array[$row['code']]= $row['name'];
}
```

If in case codes may be same and you want to get all names then you have to go for multi-dimensional array assignment like below:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $array[]= array($row['code']=>$row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the 'code' and 'name' variable comes from the `$row` if so you can use the following syntax

```
$array = [];

while(['code' => $code, 'name' => $name] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   isset($code, $name) && ($array[$code] = $name); // isset is to avoid overriding an exisiting value with null it's not needed if the query limits that case
}

print_r($array);
```

The shorthand array syntax ([]) may be used to destructure arrays for assignment  and was added in PHP 7.1 if I remember correctly